# GCP Cloud Scheduler throws ERROR for a HTTP targettype

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-scheduler

I have created a GCP Cloud Scheduler job to run every 15 minutes. It is supposed to call an API from my Node js application.
In the console the job definition looks like this:

```
Description: A job
Frequency: */15 * * * *
Timezone: Central Standard Time
Target: HTTP
URL: https://<company url>/api/email-reminder/
HTTP method: GET
Auth header: Add OIDC token
Service account: xxxxxxxxxxx-compute@developr.gserviceaccount.com
```

When it runs it returns the following in the logs:

```
httpRequest: {
 }
 insertId: "15wxxxxxxge1lv"  

jsonPayload: {
  @type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished"   
  jobName: "projects/<project name>/locations/us-central1/jobs/xxxxxxxxx-scheduler-emailreminders-1"   
  status: "UNKNOWN"   
  targetType: "HTTP"   
  url: "https://<company url>/api/email-reminder/"   
 }
 logName: "projects/<project name>/logs/cloudscheduler.googleapis.com%2Fexecutions"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2019-11-14T04:45:50.280446452Z"  

resource: {

labels: {…}   
  type: "cloud_scheduler_job"   
 }
 severity: "ERROR"  
 timestamp: "2019-11-14T04:45:50.280446452Z"  
}
```

How do I find out more information about the error?

Comment: What does StackDriver log say? It might give you some hint

Comment: The second half of my post is the StackDriver log entry for the job run.

Comment: What happens what you call the endpoint manually with curl? Configure the service account in the CLI `gcloud`. Then get an Idenity Token `gcloud auth print-identity-token`. Then execute `curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer ID_TOKEN' https://<company url>/api/email-reminder/`

Comment: I am assuming that the mistake in the service account is a typo in your question and not in the Cloud Scheduler task definition: `@developr`

Comment: Can you provide the list of role of the used service account ?

Comment: On the Cloud Scheduler Console, the "Result" of the job is stated as "Success"?    
Additionally, did you enable Cloud Scheduler API prior to March 19, 2019? If so, you may check [this](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/http-target-auth#add) information.

Comment: @JohnHanley Yes that is a typo in the post. Also, I did manually call the api and I received the expected emails.I did not use curl. I will give that a try.

Comment: Is your endpoint processing the HTTP 'Authorization" header? If not remove the auth method from Cloud Scheduler.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Here is the list of roles:  Cloud Scheduler Job Runner; Cloud SQL Client; Editor

Comment: Why did you select those roles for Cloud Scheduler and for which service account are you referring to? there is the service account that Cloud Scheduler service uses and the service account which provides the authorization identity when calling an HTTP endpoint.

Comment: @JohnHanley I removed the auth method and ran the job. It failed just like above.

Comment: @JohnHanley I am not sure why. I tried to follow the docs, but I must have misunderstood something. I am open to change.

Comment: @ArtemisGeorgakopoulou I must have enabled the api after March 19th. I have a service account in the format from the link you provided.

Comment: As @JohnHanley suggests, when you visit your Cloud IAM Console, there should be a service account associated with Cloud Scheduler with the role "Cloud Scheduler Service Agent". Can you confirm this exists in your GCP project?

Comment: The Cloud Scheduler fails either your function is public (allUsers allowed, --allow-unauthenticated option) or private?

Answer (score 9):

The default value for timeout scheduler jobs process is 180s, you can change vía gcloud command

```
gcloud scheduler jobs update http my-super-job --attempt-deadline 540s
```

As well you can see the complete info of your jobs with this commands...

```
gcloud scheduler jobs list
gcloud scheduler jobs describe my-super-job
```

Comment: Thank you, this really solved the (same) problem for me

Answer (score 2):

I've seen similar problems recently using Cloud Scheduler for HTTPS targets. Every so often, the scheduler will fail, and all I get is a log message like yours.

Viewing in the Logs Viewer, the key parts of the log are, in the log header:

```
"status":"RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED",
"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished"
```

and in the log data:

```
httpRequest: {
  status: 429   
}
jsonPayload: {
  @type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished"   
  jobName: "projects/joburlhere"   
  status: "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED"   
  targetType: "HTTP"   
  url: "https://urlgoeshere"   
}
severity: "ERROR"
```

"Resource exhausted" is the description of the 429 error code.

There's a description of this code here:

https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/errors

429 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED  Either out of resource quota or reaching rate limiting. The client should look for google.rpc.QuotaFailure error detail for more information.

Given that I'm running this Job once an hour, and the receiver is a very modest Cloud Function, I don't I'm doing anything to cause resource exhaustion. So I think it's a recurring transient problem with Google's cloud infrastructure. I'm guessing that the cloud functions were unavailable for that particular request, and because I set up the Cloud Function with default settings, the Scheduler did not retry.

Additionally, it is possible to configure a Scheduler Job to retry in case of failure. This functionality is not shown in the web console, but you can control it using the `gcloud` command.

The default setting is not to retry.

Look at the `--max-retry-attempts` flag.

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/scheduler/jobs/update/http

There are similar controls for pubsub Jobs

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/scheduler/jobs/update/pubsub

Answer (score 1):

It's because the http endpoint you specified doesn't return the response within the default attempt deadline.
[Refer the link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/scheduler/jobs/create/http#--attempt-deadline)

Comment: I suggest you to begin with checking the logs of the HTTP endpoint you specified. If it has 200 response status code to the request made by the scheduler, The answer is for you to go with. If it has some other error, you still get UNKNOWN response status. The answer specified is strongly recommended to try. My error was solved using this.